# How to sum values from object json jq

Tags: jq

How can I sum values from json object with jq

**Example input JSON object**

```json
{
  "orderNumber": 2346999,
  "workStep": 110,
  "good": 8,
  "bad": 0,
  "type": "1",
  "date": "2022-11-08T07:17:09",
  "time": 0,
  "result": 1
}
{
  "orderNumber": 2346999,
  "workStep": 110,
  "good": 8,
  "bad": 0,
  "type": "1",
  "date": "2022-11-08T07:26:57",
  "time": 0,
  "result": 1
}
```

**jq condition**

`. | select(.orderNumber==2346999 and .workStep==110) | .good`

**result**

8
8

**and I liketo have**

16

Comment: Have you tried using the `--slurp` (or `-s`) option? Then you could go with `map` and `add`, e.g. `jq -s 'map(select(.orderNumber==2346999 and .workStep==110).good) | add'`

Comment: I used  jq -s 'map(select(.orderNumber==2346999 and .workStep==110).good) | add' and is working. I like to understand map function. I saw in many solution this function. In jq play is not function. https://jqplay.org/s/DlQ7XjM0toO

Comment: it is working in jq play. You have to check the 'Slurp' option in the upper right corner

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach using `add` to get the `sum` of the numbers.

Use `map()` with `--slurp` to create an array with just the `.good` and apply `add`:

```
map(select(.orderNumber==2346999 and .workStep==110).good) | add
```

Gives: `16`

---

##### [Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/6vQ2qrVc4wC)

Answer (score 0):

An efficient approach that avoids the need to slurp is to use the general utility:

```
def count(s): reduce s as $_ (0; .+1);
```

With this, you can use your filter using jq's -n option instead of the -s option:

```
count(inputs | select(.orderNumber==2346999 and .workStep==110) | .good)
```

---

Notice that the leading `.` in your filter is unnecessary.

Comment: Did the question get edited? This doesn't answer it.

Comment: @GlennJackman - Whoops, I forgot to mention `inputs`.  Thanks.